# Is degree a "strict -transform" birational invariant for surfaces in the complex projective 3-space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, dg.differential-geometry

(Edit) My question is as follows: My previous question was about a kind of "strict-transform birational" invariant not birational invariants as usual. So I just delete the question since it complicated to state the definition and I want to think for by myself. Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you still asking a question? Is you 'previous question' in fact this question?

Comment: In order to delete the question, you should click on  "delete" at the bottom of it. Otherwise, it remains visible. 